# How to append a column delimited by a semicolon?

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file with column name separated by a semicolon. I want to append a column separated by a semicolon but it is getting separated by a comma while using csv.reader

```
with open(allFiles[0]) as csvinput:
    with open('out1.csv', 'w') as csvoutput:
        writer = csv.writer(csvoutput, lineterminator='\n')
        reader = csv.reader(csvinput)

        all = []
        row = next(reader)
        row.append('CL')
        all.append(row)

        for row in reader:
            row.append('4')
            all.append(row)

        writer.writerows(all)
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.delimiter

Comment: have you considered using pandas? The functionality for using .read_csv and to_csv is really great and you could save yourself a lot of looping ;-)

Comment: can you post a snippet of your csv file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this should work here:

```
csv.reader(csvinput, delimiter=';')
```